# How do I correctly set up Axios Interceptor in ReactJS + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I mostly use JS with React but I choose to use Typescript but for some reasons spinning up a request interceptor instance has been giving me this error:

```
src/utils/services/axios.service.ts:16:8
TS2322: Type '{ 'Content-Type': string; Accept?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "Content-Length"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "User-Agent"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "Content-Encoding"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; Authorization?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
  Type '{ 'Content-Type': string; Accept?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "Content-Length"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "User-Agent"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; "Content-Encoding"?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; Authorization?: AxiosHeaderValue | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosHeaders': set, get, has, delete, and 23 more.
    14 |   let headers = {...config.headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: `JWT ${token}`};
    15 |   if(TokenHelpers.checkIfLoggedIn()) config.headers = headers;
  > 16 |   else config.headers = {...config.headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
       |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    17 |   return config;
    18 | }, error => Promise.reject(error));
```

[image]

Here is my `axios.service.ts` file

```
import axios from "axios";
import CacheHelper from "../helpers/cacheHelper";
import TokenHelpers from "../helpers/tokenHelpers";
import CookieHelper from "../helpers/cookieHelper";
import {Configs, GeneralAppInfo} from "../helpers/constants";

const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: GeneralAppInfo.BASE_URL,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(config =\> {
let token = TokenHelpers.getToken();
let headers = {...config.headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: `JWT ${token}`};
if(TokenHelpers.checkIfLoggedIn()) config.headers = headers;
else config.headers = {...config.headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
return config;
}, error =\> Promise.reject(error));
```

[image]

I would be glad if I can get insight on how to fix this.

Comment: This should work what version of TS are you using?

What axios version are you using?

can you create working fiddle, please with same versions?

Comment: Hello @ShubhanuSharma, I am using TS: ^4.4.2 and axios: ^1.3.4

Comment: Should work. Can you create a fiddle or code sandbox, please?

Comment: Thank you @ShubhanuSharma I have figured the answer.

Comment: Hi! Please try to include the error message as text instead of an image, this way it can be searched by other users having the same problem.

Comment: Hello @Camilo yes I did , The first was a text the the second block is the screenshot for readability purpose.

Comment: Please specify how you solved it so others can also do it...

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the field to be update as against Object destructuring worked for me:

```
const instance = axios.create({baseURL: GeneralAppInfo.BASE_URL});

instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  let token = TokenHelpers.getToken(), 
       authorization = `JWT ${token}`, 
       contentType = 'application/json';

  if(TokenHelpers.checkIfLoggedIn()) {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = authorization;
    config.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
  } else config.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
  return config;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue when upgraded legacy code that used axios 0.19.x to 1.x.x ( actually went to latest currently, which is 1.6.7)

In the interceptor request code, headers object was updated dynamically, which caused same error.

```
(accessToken: string) => { 
      config.headers = {
      Accept: config.headers[Accept] || 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    }  
     return config
    }
```

In order to fix that instead of using headers object, we simply assigned header values via dot notation

```
(accessToken: string) => {
     config.headers.Accept = config.headers[Accept] ?? 'application/json'
     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    return config
  },
```

Bracket notations also works

```
config.headers['Accept'] = config.headers[Accept] ?? 'application/json'
```